# Substitute Value in dataframe based on column value in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, replace, substitution

I Have a dataframe :

```
section            name     overall   admission        room              
0        Supriya Bachal  4432837753  4431710642  4431711344
1          Meena Kumari  4432837752  4431710642  4431711344
2          Sunita Banik  4432837752  4431710643  4431711346
3          Madhuri Bhat  4432837753  4431710643  4431711347
4         Arushi Sharda  4432837753  4431710643  4431711347
5          Vishwas Kini  4432837753  4431710643  4431711347
6          Nishit goyal  4432837752  4431710642  4431711346
7         Shibiraj Soni  4432837753         NaN  4431711347
```

and other dataframe:

```
   rating     overall   admission        room
0       1  4432837749  4431710639  4431711343
1       2  4432837750  4431710640  4431711344
2       3  4432837751  4431710641  4431711345
3       4  4432837752  4431710642  4431711346
4       5  4432837753  4431710643  4431711347
```

it shows the mapping for different sections(overall,admission & room) to rating(1 to 5).

Now i want to substitute rating with their ids

Final Dataframe:

```
section            name  overall  admission  room              
0        Supriya Bachal        5          4     2
1          Meena Kumari        4          4     2
2          Sunita Banik        4          5     4
3          Madhuri Bhat        5          5     5
4         Arushi Sharda        5          5     5
5          Vishwas Kini        5          5     5
6          Nishit goyal        4          4     4
7         Shibiraj Soni        5        NaN     5
```

We have 10 columns like this and doing if else for each will not be viable

Any way to do this easily

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `DataFrame.replace`

```
df1.replace(df2.melt('rating').pivot('value', 'variable', 'rating'))
```

---

```
   section            name  overall  admission  room
0        0  Supriya Bachal      5.0        4.0   2.0
1        1    Meena Kumari      4.0        4.0   2.0
2        2    Sunita Banik      4.0        5.0   4.0
3        3    Madhuri Bhat      5.0        5.0   5.0
4        4   Arushi Sharda      5.0        5.0   5.0
5        5    Vishwas Kini      5.0        5.0   5.0
6        6    Nishit goyal      4.0        4.0   4.0
7        7   Shibiraj Soni      5.0        NaN   5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

you can map those values with setting indexed values

```
df3 = df[['section','name']]
for col in ['overall','admission', 'room']:
    df3[col] = df[col].map(df1.set_index(col)['rating'])
```

out:

```
name    overall admission   room
0   Supriya Bachal  5   4.0 2
1   Meena Kumari    4   4.0 2
2   Sunita Banik    4   5.0 4
3   Madhuri Bhat    5   5.0 5
4   Arushi Sharda   5   5.0 5
5   Vishwas Kini    5   5.0 5
6   Nishit goyal    4   4.0 4
7   Shibiraj Soni   5   NaN 5
```

Edit 1

```
#Time taken by solutions

df3 = df[['section','name']]
for col in ['overall','admission', 'room']:
    df3[col] = df[col].map(df1.set_index(col)['rating'])
2.42 ms ± 70.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#Shubham solution
%%timeit
df.replace(df1.melt('rating').pivot('value', 'variable', 'rating'))
4.82 ms ± 114 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```